# Can Microsoft Edge install Chrome Extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, microsoft-edge, chrome-web-store

I wonder if it's possible to install [Chrome Extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore) in Microsoft Edge?

Comment: @DavidPostill then what did I install? https://www.theverge.com/2020/1/16/21068646/microsoft-edge-browser-extensions-install-how-to-chrome-google

Comment: The page `edge://extensions/` exists and extensions can be installed from https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/category/Edge-Extensions

Comment: Hmm. So there's a new version of edge that will ... things I learn ...

Comment: @DavidPostill - Come our of your winter cave Chromium Edge has been in Beta for at least 7 months (1909 was being tested).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - the Chromium based versions will let you if you allow extensions from other stores.

This is Edge macOS version 79.0.309.65 showing *Privacy Badger* installed from Chrome web store.

[image: Edge]

Comment: Any Chrome extension that requires a Google account to function is not guaranteed to work.  Any extension in the Google Chrome extension store that doesn’t should work.  However, compatibility is not guaranteed, Microsoft deliberately removed some Google Chromium features.