# How can I custom the Chromium Edge built-in translator engine?

Tags: microsoft-edge

Such as change to google translate or others.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKJeQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly possible to *replace* the built-in translator easily.

However, if you want to use Google Translate, install the [Google Translate Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb) in the Chromium-based Edge.

It is possible to install extensions from Chrome Web Store in the Chromium-based Edge as per [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1518099/).

Comment: I know I can install extensions, but does it show the "translate" button in the right click menu?